# Camera and Frame Android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'am new in android progamming, and i want learn about make simple app using camera and save it in sdcard, but in camera had frame layout so when i capture with that camera, in my sdcard will show picture with frame too. I already search about camera with surface and save into sdcard, but the problem the frame not get save in that picture.. anyone can help me with tutorial?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong... your app is taking a picture and and displaying it your layout that actually puts a frame around it and when the user saves the image you want to save the image with frame over it....

Comment: before taking a picture, camera already show a frame layout, when it capture and save into jpg, i want the picture capture framy layout too.

Comment: your current output is with or without frame?

Comment: I am adding an answer... try it

Comment: i just added the answer .... check again

Comment: Do you use Camera.takePicture()? What resolution and image format do you get from the camera?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to take the snap-shot of the layout which contains the image and the frame. The snap-shot returns the bitmap which you can save. 
Here is how you can achieve this:

```
//here root layout is the layout containing the frame and the image
rootLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
// bitmap containing frame and image
Bitmap snapBmp = root.getDrawingCache();

// now you can save this bitmap
... 
...
```

Comment: This approach does not work with Surface which is used usually to display camera preview. The surface will be shown as black rectangle.